# change default font properties when composing mail in evolution

Tags: fonts, email, evolution

I'm using Evolution as a mail client. By default it's using some fonts (really I don't know) in mail. But I would like to change the font family, size and colour when I'm composing the mail to someone. When I googled I got the following links and I applied the same in my local but no use. Can you please help me to make beauty my mail? :)

http://web.mit.edu/iahn/evolution/gtkrc-mail-fonts

Note: I don't like any suggestion to switch over to other mail clients.

Answer (score 3):

I have same issue.

a/ For font type and size, go to edit/ preferences/ mail preferences/ general tab. Clear the box for "use same fonts for other applications". Click the font dialogue box immediately below. Choose your font and size.

b/ For colour, mine always defaults to a grey. I see no way to set this to black in the edits menus. I must choose the font colour for each email by using html format and clicking the colour box during composing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in Evolution, just like it's not possible to change paragraph style. This is unique and loudly advertised feature of Evolution to further streamline and converge email workflow - Evolution knows what is the best for you. Please use different email client if you are not satisfied with Evolution's choice.
(no, there is no other answer)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your Answer? As it stands, it contains no meaningful information, and doesn't cite any sources.  If this is indeed true, then providing evidence would be ideal. Also, the OP did not want a recommendation to use an alternative Mail client. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can cheat by creating a signature, but the catch is that you have to add an extra line or two to the top of your signature, then when you create new mail, instead of immediately typing, hit the down arrow to get into the top of your signature where the custom font/color begins.  Example, you would hit the down arrow and then right arrow to get to the colon in the signature, where the custom color begins:

```
:

Sincerely,

John Doe
```

Answer (score 0):

With evolution 3.42.2 forward its possible as suggested on the mailinglist: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/evolution-list/2022-February/msg00029.html

Create a `body-font.js` file in `~/.local/share/evolution/webkit-editor-plugins` with the content:

```js
'use strict';

var localhostBodyFontPlugin = {
  name : "localhostBodyFontPlugin",
  setup : function(doc) {
    if (doc.body) {
      doc.body.setAttribute("style", "font-family:Arial,sans-serif;")
    }
  }
};

EvoEditor.RegisterPlugin(localhostBodyFontPlugin);
``
```